# PHP Fizzbuzz Challenge

Tags: php, fizzbuzz

Someone at work as poised the challenge to create a script that prints the FizzBuzz game in as few likes as possible using PHP

The challenge

> Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “FizzBuzz”.

My attempt:

```
foreach(range(1,100) as $i) {
  $val = ($i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : "").($i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : "");
  echo (empty($val) ? $i : $val) .  '<br />';
}
```

Someone's Pythons attempt

```
[ ("Fizz" if not i % 3 else "") + ("Buzz" if not i % 5 else "") + ("Baz" if not i % 7 else "") if _ else "" for i in range(0, 100) ]
```

Can you see how to make this better/improve it? Or even do it better?

Thanks for your time

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could it be moved instead of closed?

Comment: I've flagged it for moderator attention to see if it can be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach(range(1,100)as$i)echo(''==($x=($i%3==0?"Fizz":"").($i%5==0?"Buzz":""))?$i:$x).'<br />';`

Answer (score 20):

The most optimized version:

```
echo "1\n2\nFizz\n4\nBuzz\nFizz\n7\n8\nFizz\nBuzz\n11\nFizz\n13\n14\nFizzBuzz\n16\n17\nFizz\n19\nBuzz\nFizz\n22\n23\nFizz\nBuzz\n26\nFizz\n28\n29\nFizzBuzz\n31\n32\nFizz\n34\nBuzz\nFizz\n37\n38\nFizz\nBuzz\n41\nFizz\n43\n44\nFizzBuzz\n46\n47\nFizz\n49\nBuzz\nFizz\n52\n53\nFizz\nBuzz\n56\nFizz\n58\n59\nFizzBuzz\n61\n62\nFizz\n64\nBuzz\nFizz\n67\n68\nFizz\nBuzz\n71\nFizz\n73\n74\nFizzBuzz\n76\n77\nFizz\n79\nBuzz\nFizz\n82\n83\nFizz\nBuzz\n86\nFizz\n88\n89\nFizzBuzz\n91\n92\nFizz\n94\nBuzz\nFizz\n97\n98\nFizz\nBuzz\n";
```

Comment: (Unless someone posts the same  thing without the space after the `echo` and the last `\n`...

Comment: +1 Wow. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: You can write it more succintly (and equally performantly) by omitting the echo, double quotes, semicolon, opening and closing PHP tags, and replacing the "\n"s with actual newlines.

Comment: @AndreaFaulds the challenge was to write it with as few lines as possible :)

Answer (score 5):

One size optimizations:

```
$val = ($i % 3 ? "" : "Fizz").($i % 5 ? "" : "Buzz");
              ^--- remove == 0       ^--- remove  == 0
```

PHP will handily convert the result of the modulo to a boolean for you, without the equality test.

And similarly

```
echo (!$val ? $i : $val);
```

No need for the empty() test - empty strings evaluate as a boolean false anyways.

And if you're on PHP 5.3+, you can use the shortcut ternary as well:

```
echo ($val ?: $i)
```

Comment: You mean `($i % 3 ? "" : "Fizz")` right?